# SwiftUI Why would the input on Picker not be functioning?

Tags: ios, swiftui, binding, state, picker

I am quite new to SwiftUI and I would need the community help to understand why in the following code the selection of any of the Picker options does not seem to work, either is not selectable and therefore does not trigger any action or it gets selected and it does not trigger anything.

Many thanks in advance for letting me know the underlining concept.

Devo

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var measureToConvert = ""
    
    @State private var conversionFromMeasure = "km"
    
    @State private var convertedToMeasure = "m"
    
    let measure = ["m", "km", "ft", "yd", "mi"]
    
    
    func convertInMillimeters(input: String, number: String) -> Double {
        
        var value: Double = 0
        
        if let realNumber = Double(number) {
        
        switch input {
        
        case "m":
            
            let conversion = (Double(realNumber) * 1_000)
            
            value = conversion
        
        case "km":
            let conversion = (Double(realNumber) * 1_000_000)
            value = conversion
            
        case "ft":
            let conversion = (Double(realNumber) * 304.8)
            value = conversion
            
        case "yd":
            let conversion = (Double(realNumber) * 914.4)
            return conversion
            
        case "mi":
            let conversion = (Double(realNumber) * 1_609_344)
            value = conversion
        default:
            
            let conversion = -2.0
            
            value = conversion
            }
           
        }
        
        print("value in millimeters is \(value)")
        return value
        

    }



    func convertToNewMeasure(input: String, number: Double) -> Double {
        
        var value: Double = 0
        
        switch input {
        
        case "m" :
            
            let conversion = (number / 1_000)
            
            value = conversion
        
        case "km":
            let conversion = (number / 1_000_000)
            value = conversion
            
        case "ft":
            let conversion = (number / 304.8)
            value = conversion
            
        case "yd":
            let conversion = (number / 914.4)
            return conversion
            
        case "mi":
            let conversion = (number / 1_609_344)
            value = conversion
        
        default:
            
            let conversion = -1.0
            
            value = conversion
            }
           
        
        print("value converted is \(value)")
        return value
        
    }
    
    var inMillimeters : Double {
       return convertInMillimeters(input: conversionFromMeasure, number: measureToConvert)
    }

    var result: Double {
        
        return convertToNewMeasure(input: convertedToMeasure, number: inMillimeters)
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView{
        
        Form{
        
            
            Section(header: Text("Value to convert:")){
            TextField("Enter a measure", text: $measureToConvert).keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            
            }
            
            
            
        Section(header: Text("Select input measure")){
            Picker("From", selection: $conversionFromMeasure) {
                ForEach(0 ..< measure.count){
                    Text("\(self.measure[$0])")
                    
                    
                }
                
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        }
      
        
        Section(header: Text("Select output measure")){
            Picker("To", selection: $convertedToMeasure) {
                ForEach(0 ..< measure.count) {
                    Text("\(self.measure[$0])")
                    
                }
                
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())        }
            
            
        
        
            Section(header: Text("Converted value")){
                Text("\(result, specifier: "%.2f")")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Measure Converter")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: The picker was not working because it did not have a group of items to *pick* from. You'll see in my answer that the picker now has a selection of items to pick from

Comment: Thanks a million for the quick solution, I will study straight away. Thanks again, I have really appreciated the help!

Answer (score 0):

when using a picker with this few options, its very convenient using an enum to store the values, you can also use an enum to store your functions and return your desired result. You can learn more about enums [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html)

Once you have the enum created, then make it conform to CaseIterable which will give you an array of all your cases which you will then use in your ForEach.

You also give it a rawValue which will serve as the content which will populate each picker option. Its pretty clear what I did in the code there.

```
 import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    enum Unit: String, CaseIterable {
        case meters = "m"
        case kilometers = "km"
        case feet = "ft"
        case yards = "yd"
        case miles = "mi"
        
    }
    
    @State private var unitSelection: Unit = .meters
    @State private var measureToConvert = ""
    
    @State private var conversionFromMeasure = "km"
    
    @State private var convertedToMeasure = "m"
    
    let measure = ["m", "km", "ft", "yd", "mi"]
    
    
    func convertInMillimeters(input: String, number: String) -> Double {
        
        var value: Double = 0
        
        if let realNumber = Double(number) {
        
        switch input {
        
        case "m":
            
            let conversion = (Double(realNumber) * 1_000)
            
            value = conversion
        
        case "km":
            let conversion = (Double(realNumber) * 1_000_000)
            value = conversion
            
        case "ft":
            let conversion = (Double(realNumber) * 304.8)
            value = conversion
            
        case "yd":
            let conversion = (Double(realNumber) * 914.4)
            return conversion
            
        case "mi":
            let conversion = (Double(realNumber) * 1_609_344)
            value = conversion
        default:
            
            let conversion = -2.0
            
            value = conversion
            }
           
        }
        
        print("value in millimeters is \(value)")
        return value
        

    }



    func convertToNewMeasure(input: String, number: Double) -> Double {
        
        var value: Double = 0
        
        switch input {
        
        case "m" :
            
            let conversion = (number / 1_000)
            
            value = conversion
        
        case "km":
            let conversion = (number / 1_000_000)
            value = conversion
            
        case "ft":
            let conversion = (number / 304.8)
            value = conversion
            
        case "yd":
            let conversion = (number / 914.4)
            return conversion
            
        case "mi":
            let conversion = (number / 1_609_344)
            value = conversion
        
        default:
            
            let conversion = -1.0
            
            value = conversion
            }
           
        
        print("value converted is \(value)")
        return value
        
    }
    
    var inMillimeters : Double {
       return convertInMillimeters(input: conversionFromMeasure, number: measureToConvert)
    }

    var result: Double {
        
        return convertToNewMeasure(input: convertedToMeasure, number: inMillimeters)
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView{
        
        Form{
        
            
            Section(header: Text("Value to convert:")){
            TextField("Enter a measure", text: $measureToConvert).keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            
            }
            
            
            
        Section(header: Text("Select input measure")){
            Picker("From", selection: $unitSelection) {
                ForEach(Unit.allCases, id: \.self){ unit in
                    Text(unit.rawValue)
                    
                    
                }
                
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        }
      
        
        Section(header: Text("Select output measure")){
            Picker("To", selection: $convertedToMeasure) {
                ForEach(0 ..< measure.count) {
                    Text("\(self.measure[$0])")
                    
                }
                
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())        }
            
            
        
        
            Section(header: Text("Converted value")){
                Text("\(result, specifier: "%.2f")")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Measure Converter")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your Pickers working by changing this:

```
ForEach(0 ..< measure.count){
    Text("\(self.measure[$0])")
}
```

to this:

```
ForEach(measure, id: \.self) {
    Text($0)
}
```

So the two sections should be:

```
Section(header: Text("Select input measure")){
    Picker("From", selection: $conversionFromMeasure) {
        ForEach(measure, id: \.self) {
            Text($0)
        }
    }
    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
}
            
Section(header: Text("Select output measure")){
    Picker("To", selection: $convertedToMeasure) {
        ForEach(measure, id: \.self) {
            Text($0)
        }
    }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
}
```

Comment: That's great, thanks a million I am learning a lot through all your input. Thanks again.